# AdMob error (Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView)

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, adview

I try to put AdMob, copied the library in libs, registered in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

added in a separate Layout code:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:orientation="horizontal" 
              android:gravity="center" 
              > 
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView" 
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                           ads:adUnitId="my cod" 
                           ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER" 
                           ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/> 

</LinearLayout>
```

in Activity:

```
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView); 
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

in the graphical viewer everything looks fine.

but when you start the emulator climbs error:

```
03-09 10:21:10.509      935-935/my.ideal E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.ideal/my.ideal.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #259: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #259: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267) 
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895) 
        at my.ideal.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.ads.AdView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my.ideal-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/my.ideal-2, /system/lib]] 
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53) 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267) 
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895) 
        at my.ideal.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the device also does not start, use Android Studio.

What to do?

Comment: Does anything change if you set `ads:loadAdOnCreate="false"` ?

Comment: thanks for the answer. there is no such option does not work: (

Answer (score 3):

I think your mistake is related to the class name. This should be:

```
<activity
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
   android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

Instead of: `com.google.ads.AdActivity`

Comment: If he uses the old admob api then `com.google.ads...` package should be fine

Comment: Yes I always use com.google.ads...changed api 17 does not work on the emulator, and real device :(

Comment: manifest: `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />`

Comment: helped me: `Build > Rebuild Project`